# Why can't a Java enum be final?

Tags: java, enums, final

```
public interface Proposal  {  
    public static final enum STATUS { 
        NEW ,
        START ,
        CONTINUE ,
        SENTTOCLIENT
    }; 
}
```

Java does not allow an enum to be `final` inside an interface, but by default every data member inside an interface is `public static final`. Can anybody clarify this?

Comment: Is it that you think a "non final" enum is somehow subclassable?

Comment: no i knew enum cannot be subclass but java gives us freedom to write final in from any constant in interface but not in front of enum why this partially that is what i was asking(just trying to read what is there in their mind while doing this?)

Comment: there is an enormous difference between how `final` is used between class/interface (and, in principle, enum) definitions and member *field* definitions (which is what "constants" usually are in an interface).  One affects subclassability, and the other affects mutability.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An enum can't be final, because the compiler will generate subclasses for each enum entry that the programmer has explicitly defined an implementation for.

Moreover, an enum where no instances have their own class body is implicitly final, by [JLS section 8.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9).

Answer (score 40):

Java does not allow you to create a class that extends an `enum` type. Therefore, enums themselves are always final, so using the `final` keyword is superfluous.

Of course, in a sense, `enum`s are not final because you can define an anonymous subclass for each field inside of the enum descriptor. But it wouldn't make much sense to use the `final` keyword to prevent those types of descriptions, because people would have to create these subclasses within the same .java file, and anybody with rights to do that could just as easily remove the `final` keyword. There's no risk of someone extending your enum in some other package.

Comment: Completely confusing answer. If you look at the source of java.lang.Enum class, you can see that it is not final but an abstract class.

Comment: Nevertheless, no `enum` type can be subclassed.

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov: the `Enum` class is abstract because you have to be able to extend it. But the actual `enum`s that extend it get defined by the compiler as `final` classes. See http://mindprod.com/jgloss/enum.html#UNDERTHEHOOD1

Comment: Just to rephrase it, `java.lang.Enum` is abstract because all enums declared with `enum` keyword is converted into subclasses of `java.lang.Enum` class by the compiler.

Answer (score 8):

Two things:

1. enums are final subclasses of java.lang.Enum
2. if an enum is a member of a class, it is implicitly static

Answer (score 2):

No point in declaring enum final. Final for classes means that they can not be inherited. However, enums can not be inherited by default (that is they are final).

The final thing is valid only for variables. However you should think of the enums more like data types than variables.