# How can I override toString() Method for all enum classes?

Tags: java, enums, tostring

Is it possible to override the method `toString` for all `Enum` classes, rather than overriding it only in the enum class. Example:

#### Coins.java:

```
enum Coins { PENNY(1), POUND(100), NOTE(500); 

    private int value;

    Coins(int coinValue) {
         value = coinValue;
    }
     [...] // Other code

    public String toString() {
         return name().charAt(0) + name().substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

#### DaysOfWeek.java:

```
enum DaysOfWeek { MONDAY(1), TUESDAY(2), WEDNESDAY(3);
   
     private int dayID;

     DaysOfWeek(int ID) {
        dayID = ID;
     }
       [...] // Other code

     public String toString() {
         return name().charAt(0) + name().substring(1).toLowerCase();
     }
 }
```

Currently, I have to override `toString()` in each enum class. Can I create a generic `toString` method that will override all classes that are of enum type without actually writing `toString` in every enum type class?

Comment: No. Lets say that you overridden this method for all classes in two enum types. Which `toString` code should be executed?

Comment: @Pshemo The toString method that was declared in that enum would be executed when you call the method from that enum. But if it is not possible to override all enum classes, then isn't this inefficient typing toString in every enum class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. You can't override the system's `Enum` class, and you cannot make a subclass from which all of your `Enum`s inherit from as it is [a language feature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) with [a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19433364/1768232) [of special](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9891613/1768232) [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3664077/1768232). However, you can make a static helper method:

```
public class Utils {
  public static String toEnumString(Enum<?> inputEnum) {
    return inputEnum.name().charAt(0) + inputEnum.name().substring(1).toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

This can be used in two different ways:

1. You can still override `toString()` in your enums, but with a lot less chance for copy paste error, and the ability to change it everyone with one code change. e.g.

   ```
   enum Coins { PENNY(1), POUND(100), NOTE(500); 

     // snip 
     public String toString() {
       return Utils.toEnumString(this);
     }
   }
   ```
2. You can use it in other methods, for example:

   ```
   System.out.println(Utils.toEnumString(Coins.PENNY));
   preparedStatement.setString(1, Utils.toEnumString(Coins.POUND));
   ```

---

You can also use Apache Commons or Google Guava to do the same thing, if you want to add another library to your project:

- Apache Commons: [`WordUtils.capitalizeFully`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully(java.lang.String))
- Guava: [`CaseFormat.UpperCamel`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/master/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.html#UPPER_CAMEL)

Comment: You could also use [`WordUtils.capitalizeFully`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully(java.lang.String)), invoking it as `return capitalizeFully(inputEnum.name())`.

Comment: Can you give an example on how to use the helper method toEnumString() that you used?

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a delegate/utlity/helper that all the enum toString() methods call. This avoids having to call a utility class whenever you wish to convert to a String.

```
private static class CommonEnumToString {
    static String toString(Enum<?> e) {
        return e.name().charAt(0) + e.name().substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Update the toString() to call the helper

```
enum Coins {
    PENNY(1), POUND(100), NOTE(500);
    private int value;
    Coins(int coinValue) {
        value = coinValue;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return CommonEnumToString.toString(this);
    }
}

enum DaysOfWeek {
    MONDAY(1), TUESDAY(2), WEDNESDAY(3);
    private int dayID;
    DaysOfWeek(int ID) {
        dayID = ID;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return CommonEnumToString.toString(this);
    }
}
```

Test

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(DaysOfWeek.WEDNESDAY); // ==> Wednesday
    System.out.println(Coins.PENNY);          // ==> Penny
}
```