# Test in error: Unable to initialize @Spy annotated field 'resource' / design advise

Tags: unit-testing, enums, mockito

Why can't I spy on an enum method? I can mock and spy on everything else I need but when I try to spy on an enum my tests don't run anymore and I just get an initialization error.

Enum class:

```
public enum DomainResource implements SoapUpdate {

 ENUM1(new PUpdate()),
 ENUM2(new SUpdate());

 private DomainResource(SoapUpdate update){
   this.update = update;
 }

 private final SoapUpdate update;

 @Override
 public void apply(SoapService svc, byte[] resp ) throws Exception {
   update.apply(svc, resp)
 }
}
```

Class to test:

```
public class ProcessUpdateMessage implements Function<UpdateMessage, MessageResult> {

  private DomainResource resource;

  public MessageResult apply( UpdateMessage t ){

    ..
    resource = getResourceType( t.getUrl() )
    ..
    resource.apply( soapService, dropwizardResponse );
  }

}
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UpdateMessageTest {

  // other spies and mocks working correctly

  @Spy
  DomainResource resource; // error here

  @InjectMocks
  ProcessUpdateMessage puma = new ProcessUpdateMessage(null, null, "");

  @Test
  ...
}
```

And (I didn't write that class) isn't it bad design to put logic into a java enum?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like Mockito can't mock/spy on enums since they're final and have static methods. Enums can be mocked using PowerMock though.

In my case I've solved replacing SoapUpdate with DomainResource in the class to test and mocking that interface in my test. Not sure if it's the best solution..

Comment: Apologies if it's lazy but here's  "Static Methods are death to testability", Misko Hevery : http://googletesting.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/static-methods-are-death-to-testability.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mockito [doesn't allow mocking final classes](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ), and that includes enums, which are [effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891613/why-cant-a-java-enum-be-final). However, the error is in the design of ProcessUpdateMessage, not the enum type.

The enum type and especially the values in your example are poorly named, which might explain why you have doubts about the design of that code.  But whoever wrote the enum **DID give you a way to mock it** (as your comment suggests you discovered), by making it implement the interface `SoapUpdate`. You need to change the type of `ProcessUpdateMessage.resource` to `SoapUpdate`, and then you can at least mock it (though looking at your code I wonder if in your test, which is not shown, the injected mock will not be overwritten by the result of the call to `getResourceType`).

In answer to your last question about best practices, adding logic to an enum value is totally in keeping with the best practice known as [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). An enum type represents a choice among a known and finite set of possibilities. If it's a choice that implies a behavior, you can either force whatever method receives the enum to implement a bug-prone and redundant switch statement specifying the behavior for all possible values of the enum, or you can have it call a method on the enum value.  This is a clear case of DRY and it also impacts the [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your exhaustive answer!
Sorry for the enum naming they're not the real ones. Yes I've mocked out also the getResourceType call and changed the "resource" type into SoapUpdate as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Here one of my tests / my solution:

```
@Test
public void testSoapServiceCallwithDWResponse200AndSoapProblem(){

  UpdateMessage um = new UpdateMessage( "ID/123", "POST" , "/domain/resourcename/id_123" );
  int status = 200;
  String jsonResp = "{aLotOf:\"json\"}";

  doReturn( response ) //mocked
  .when( connector ).getLatestStateOfResource( anyString() );

  prepareResponseMockedEntityAndStatus( status, jsonResp );

  MockResource mockResource = new MockResource( "exception - resp status "+status );

  doReturn( mockResource )
  .when( puma ).getResourceType( anyString() );

  MessageResult processingResult = puma.apply( um );

  // a few verify..

  Assert.assertTrue( mockResource.times() == 1 );

  Assert.assertTrue( processingResult == MessageResult.NACK_REQUEUE );

}


class MockResource implements SoapUpdate{  

  private String name;
  private int calls;

  public MockResource( String name ){
    this.name = name;
    calls = 0;
  }

  public int times(){
    return calls;
  }

  @Override
  public void apply( SoapService svc, byte[] resp ) throws Exception {

    calls++;

    if( name.contains( "exception" ) ){
      throw new Exception( name + " - Mocked `response.apply()` throws an excpt");
    }

    System.out.println( name + " - DB behind soap service UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY" );
  }
```

}